cPanel node.js app HTML file not loading external resources
my VPS is CloudLinux v7.9.0 STANDARD kvm using cPanel v110.0.24
I've set up a node.js app in cPanel. The apps webroot is apps/sitecache and the app URL is sitecache, the startup file is app.js. Basics are working fine - http://cache.4x4tyres.co.uk/sitecache/ - but on a particular endpoint http://cache.4x4tyres.co.uk/sitecache/test I am just using -
app.get(root + '/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

which just sends the contents of the index.html file to the browser.
The contents of index.html are simply:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test HTML file</title>
    <script src="/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>I'm a simple html file</body>
</html>

If you look at the console for the above URL, you will see that there is a 404 error where it's trying to load /load.js
I believe that this same issue would arise if I tried to use something like socket.io which relies on an external resource being loaded in the html file.
So the question I have is how do get external resources like this loading properly in a cPanel node.js application?
As a I side note, I also noticed that when I set up the node.js app, it also created me a sitecache directory in public_html and in there is a new .htaccess file with the contents:
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/cache4x4tyresco/apps/sitecache"
PassengerBaseURI "/sitecache"
PassengerNodejs "/home/cache4x4tyresco/nodevenv/apps/sitecache/12/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile app.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

Not sure if that is relevant here, but thought it best to include.
Many thanks

Where is this load.js file located? The leading slash means the URL is relative to the domain root, so this resolves to the absolute URL http://cache.4x4tyres.co.uk/load.js here - is that actually the correct one?

@CBroe - it's located in the same location as the app.js file. Interestingly when I change the location to /sitecache/load.js I get an error:
The resource from “http://cache.4x4tyres.co.uk/sitecache/load.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). - however if I do try and just load http://cache.4x4tyres.co.uk/sitecache/load.js in a browser, that gives a 404

Because that URL results in a 404, you get a response that explicitly has the Content-Type set to text/html - and therefor the browser refuses to interpret it as JavaScript. (Which would not make sense here anyway, since it is not JavaScript to begin with.)
